# Heap memory for a program

Tags: c, linux, unix

If I did not use any malloc or calloc function in my c program. So, at that
time the starting and ending address of heap memory of a program is same or different ? which means, what is the size of the heap memory.

Comment: The C runtime library might allocate on the heap.

Comment: It seems, you have two question, which are different

Comment: Did you use any (third-party) libs? Because it's entirely possible for them to use heap memory, without you calling `malloc` anywhere

Comment: The following is my program:                                                                           int main()
{
 return 36;
}                                                                                                                          
    What is the size of the heap memory for above program.

Comment: @mohanraj: You only know by _measuring_. It may (and likely is) different for different systems (compiler [GCC vs. clang], compiler version, architecture, …).

Comment: So, is there any way to measure this.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely implementation dependent. Your C runtime library/startup code may already put things on the heap before your `main` function is called.

Comment: If I did not use any header file?

Comment: `header file` != `runtime library`

Comment: When you're linking your program, a static part is injected (for GCC, that's usually `crt1.o` or `crti.o`) which prepares the C environment. The real entry point of your program that is called by the Linux kernel is actually `_start`. It prepares the C environment and then calls your `main` function. The entry point might be different on other OSs, but the principle is always the same: before your `main` is called, there is code injected by the compiler that is running. This is independent of any use of headers.